# How to hide brackets and create bars over variables

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

I have two problems figuring out how to format my formulas properly so that when I print out the notebook the formulas look like the ones in my textbook.

So far I've got this:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^5 x[[i]]-x$

but ideally I would want the i to be without the double square brackets, and also I would want a bar over the $2$nd $x$, and to make it the mean of the list $x$.

Comment: In my opinion you should keep input code separate from output formatting; attempting to write your Notebooks such that input *looks* like standard notation but *evaluates* as the *Mathematica* code you want will usually lead to frustration.  Is this what you are attempting?

Comment: Yes, it was 8) What would be the best way for creating a document that can be printed out that contains standard notation, but also has calculations that I can execute?

Comment: There *are* ways do to this, but they should be considered special-case-tools rather than standard practice.  I don't have time for a proper answer now but look at [`Interpretation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpretation.html) as a start.  You could use [my `AutoCollapse` code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/683/121) or even [`AutoDestruct`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13417/121) with input cells which `CellPrint` other input cells containing `InterpretationBox` expressions.  If that doesn't scare you off I can try to provide an example later.

Comment: I agree with @Mr.Wizard, but you could look at these examples: [Representation of product with exclusions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17978/245), [Can I enter the traditional form for Binomial as input in an expression?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45488/245). There are many others. Also, you can allow *Mathematica* to evaluate `TraditionalForm` input.