# How can I create a "Run all code" button in a notebook?

Tags: evaluation, notebooks, button, interface, run

How can I create the "Run all code" button (at the top right corner) in Mathematica notebook?

The current method I have is to save the .nb file into .wls (i.e. Wolfram Language Script), and then open the .wls file (which have a "Run all code" button at the top right corner) and save it back to .nb file. But this method seems silly and clumsy and I wonder if there's a better method to do it.

Comment: You can also go into the "Evaluation" menu and click on "Evaluate Notebook"...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is some code I wrote to make a palette that I use a lot. Maybe the it will work you, or at least give you ideas on how to do it.

```
CreatePalette[
  Framed @ Column[{
     Button["Evaluate Cells", 
       FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["EvaluateCells"]], 
       Appearance -> "Palette", ImageSize -> 140],
     Button["Evaluate Notebook", 
       FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["EvaluateNotebook"]], 
       Appearance -> "Palette", ImageSize -> 140],
     Button["Global Clear", Clear["Global`*"],
       Appearance -> "Palette", ImageSize -> 140]}],
  WindowTitle -> "Evaluation"];
```

[image: palette]

If you need instructions on how to install the palette, look at [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77332/3066).