# Auto Execute Notebook on Open

Tags: scripting, automation

How might I automatically execute a notebook script on open?

For example I would like to a notebook to automatically execute it's cells.

Comment: You can probably use this: [7198](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7198/5478)

Comment: Have you considered to use a Package instead of a Notebook?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it using the option IntializationCell, moreover there are complementary options for controlling its behavior.

Here is the documentation on how to achieve it 
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/InitializationCell.html