# How to run code in a saved file when it is opened

Tags: functions

I have a *Mathematica* file that I saved.  In it, I have multiple functions that I've defined and have evaluated a number of the functions with different arguments.  I would like to be able to open the file and essentially execute the commands at once without having to select and run each individual function.  I know Maple used to have a function that did this, but does *Mathematica* have one?

Comment: If you want to evaluate your file without opening Mathematica's notebook GUI you might want to use it as a [script](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframLanguageScripts.html). If you want to evaluate the cells when you open a notebook you can use [initialization cells](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/InitializationCell.html). If you want to evaluate the cells inside Mathematica all at once, but want to start it yourself, you can choose Evaluation -> Evaluate Notebook. There are some other options there as well.

Comment: @Pickett if this is not a duplicate your comment deserves conversion into an answer.

Comment: Okay, i understand now.  I'm much more familiar with Maple, but my school offers Mathematica free for students, so I'm getting familiarized.  The Evaluation tab and evaluate notebook worked exactly like I wanted.  Thank you.  And yes, if you convert to an answer I'll upvote it.

Comment: Related [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7198/3066).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three options that spring to mind:

- You can run *Mathematica* code without opening a notebook by treating it as a [*Mathematica* script](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframLanguageScripts.html).
- You can tell *Mathematica* to evaluate certain cells every time the notebook opens by designating those cells as [initialization cells](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/InitializationCell.html).
- Under the evaluation tab in the menu there are different options for queueing cells for evaluation, for example Evaluate -> Evaluate Notebook.